# how does GTM collect data from ios?

Tags: google-tag-manager

gtm=googletagmanager,
I used gtm in our ios app,
but the way to integrate it confused me.
all I need is only a container,a json file, putting it into a root path of the project.

how did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like gtm can access the container file, 
and if you have looked the json file, 
it include a lot of information, like all the value you want to collect triggers, trackID etc.
I use GTM+firebase, the firebase actually collects the data from app, and then give gtm.